# AWS Autoscaling on CPU for any number of EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

We currently have a cloud formation template across all of our EC2 instances with the following policy:

- Scale up when avg CPU > 90%
- Scale down when avg CPU < 50%

This works really well, but as we grow in servers, the spread is too much, as we decrease our servers, the spread is too little.

For example if we had 100 EC2 instances running this might be more ideal:

- Scale up when avg CPU > 95%
- Scale down when avg CPU < 90%

For example if we had just 2 EC2 instances running this might be more ideal:

- Scale up when avg CPU > 80%
- Scale down when avg CPU < 25%

If you don't do that, then you end up either burning money on servers, or having your autoscale just keep cycling between a scale up and scale down event constantly.

I'm wondering if anybody knows a way to define scale up and scale down policies depending on the number of instances you have?  Or perhaps a different formula to use rather than just taking the average CPU?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify more than one auto scaling group.  Each group would have its own set of policies.  On the first group, set the maximum number of instances to 50, and make the policy scale up at 80% cpu.  Make the second group scale up at 90%.